# What do the numbers in the tcsh history file mean?

Tags: linux, history, tcsh

What do the numbers in the tcsh history file mean?

```
[root@localhost ~]# vi /home/test/.history
#+1572853835
su 0-
#+1572854170
history -a
#+1572854172
history -w
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems like those are [Unix Timestamps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) you can convert them to human readable timestamps using this link: https://www.epochconverter.com/